# Recommended way of adding OAuth + views to a Rails API ONLY app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, alexa-skills-kit

I started using Rails fairly recently. I have an API I built with it for a mobile app that's being used in production and it works great.

I now require User authentication in it.

I initially went with a devise/custom JWT warden strategy which seemed to be working just fine for me, but I'm now forced to implement an authentication code OAuth flow. I need to link an Alexa skill to my service.

For this, I need to throw a webpage saying "Alexa wants to access your data for this skill" and proceed to authenticate

The OAuth provider bit is easily possible with Doorkeeper and their wonderful docs.

With my shortsighted-ness, I made a Rails API-only app so I'm pretty clueless on how to achieve said objective.

Answer (score 2):

Try inheriting your controller with `ActionController::Base` and create views folder and add the view file in that.

It should work.

Comment: Hey Lavika, thanks for your swift response! 
I have one more question :

Is this a standard approach to securing Rails APIs - considering OAuth being an industry standard and Rails API mode is part of the main rails gem since Rails 5?